# Picker View does not reappear once dismissed, and text field clicked a second time

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview

Here's a simplified code, with a view controller with just a text field I also updated the title to reflect the newer issue.

When run, I click the text field and it brings up the picker view, and I'm able to click a value on the picker view and it shows up on the text field. I'm able to dismiss the picker view now when I press the Done button on the navigation bar. But now when I click the text field a second time, I don't get the picker view to pop up a second time.

## import

```
@interface MyPickerViewViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate,
                                                      UIPickerViewDataSource,
                                                      UITextFieldDelegate>

@end


@interface MyPickerViewViewController () {
    UIPickerView *_pv;
    NSArray *_array;
    IBOutlet __weak UITextField *_tf;
}

@end

@implementation MyPickerViewViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _pv = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _pv.dataSource = self;
    _pv.delegate = self;
    _tf.inputView = _pv;

    UIToolbar*  mypickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 56)];
    mypickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [mypickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked:)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];
    [mypickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    _tf.inputAccessoryView = mypickerToolbar;

    _tf.delegate = self;

}

- (void)pickerDoneClicked:(id)sender
{
    [_pv removeFromSuperview];
    [_tf.inputView removeFromSuperview];
    [_tf.inputAccessoryView removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Added this method and now the picker view comes up every time I
// click on the text field, even after I dismiss it. However, the
// picker view is in wrong place, so I just have to adjust the
// CGRect assigned to it.
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.view addSubview:_tf.inputAccessoryView];
    [self.view addSubview:_tf.inputView];
    return NO;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"Hello there");
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated
{

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(    NSInteger)component
{
    return [_array objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _array.count;
}

- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    _tf.text = [_array objectAtIndex:row];
}    

@end
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I do not add my picker view to my view's subview, which is what the link I provided does. That doesn't work for me.

Comment: Put breakpoint in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and see if it goes there, the next time you tap the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this:

```
[datePicker removeFromSuperview];
[pickerView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Like I said, I don't add the picker view as subviews to my view, so I didn't include those lines. But I tried, and the picker view disappears alright, but the toolbar that contains the Done button persists.

Comment: Ok I added [_titleField.inputAccessoryView removeFromSuperview];
    [_titleField.inputView removeFromSuperview]; and both picker and toolbar disappeared. NEW issue: now when click the text field again, the picker does not show. I'd have to click another text field, then click back to this text field for the picker to show up again

Comment: Could you please update your answer with the new code? Also, could you provide code for method where you load the picker?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in textFieldDidBeginEditing and see if it goes there, the next time you tap the textfield.

Comment: I did, and I don't hit the break point, and that's why I'm wondering.

Comment: Could you try and change `[_tf resignFirstResponder];` to `[textfield resignFirstResponder];` ?

Comment: I did this to no avail. Then I read about returning NO for textFieldShouldBeginEditing. See update.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

in your action method

Comment: Thanks, but that did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

See update with this addition

```
// Added this method and now the picker view comes up every time I
// click on the text field, even after I dismiss it. However, the
// picker view is in wrong place, so I just have to adjust the
// CGRect assigned to it.
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{    
    [self.view addSubview:_tf.inputAccessoryView];
    [self.view addSubview:_tf.inputView];
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an adjusted CGRect for the pickerview and tool bar that worked. I was wondering though if there is a default height for a pickerview?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", nil];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    CGRect viewRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat pvHeight = 235;
    CGFloat pvYpos = viewRect.size.height - pvHeight;

    CGRect pvRect = CGRectMake(viewRect.origin.x, pvYpos, viewRect.size.width, pvHeight);
    _pv = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pvRect];
    _pv.dataSource = self;
    _pv.delegate = self;
    _tf.inputView = _pv;

    CGFloat tbYpos = pvYpos-44;
    UIToolbar*  mypickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, tbYpos, viewRect.size.width, 44)];
    mypickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [mypickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked:)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];
    [mypickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    _tf.inputAccessoryView = mypickerToolbar;

    _tf.delegate = self;

}
```